# How do I store an array of records into each field without having to define the array position?

Tags: java, arrays, records

I'm trying to prompt the user for the information and writing it into a text file then the program reads from the text file and there is a counter determining the length of the array record. But I am currently stuck at how I can store each field into an array of record without defining the array position. So far it is successful at reading from the text file but when I write into that text file, there will be a null pointer exception error.

This is a snippet of my code

```
static class publisherDetails
{
    String pubID;
    String publisher;
    String pubAddress;
}

public static void publisherDetails() throws IOException
{
    File publisherMain = new File("publisherMain.txt");
    Scanner readpublisher = new Scanner(publisherMain);
    publisherDetails [] publisherList = new 
    publisherDetails[countPubLines(0, publisherMain)];
    createPublisher(publisherList, publisherMain, readpublisher);
    readpublisher.close();
    printPublisher(publisherList);
}

public static int countPubLines(int count, File publisherMain) throws IOException
{
  Scanner countingLines = new Scanner(publisherMain);

  while (countingLines.hasNextLine())
  {
     String reading = countingLines.nextLine();
     count++;
  } 

  countingLines.close();
  count = count/3;
  return count;
}

public static void createPublisher(publisherDetails[] publisherList, File publisherMain, Scanner readpublisher) throws IOException
{
while ( readpublisher.hasNextLine() )
    {
       for (int i=0; i< publisherList.length; i++) 
       publisherList[i] = new publisherDetails();
        {
          publisherList[0].pubID = readpublisher.nextLine();
          publisherList[0].publisher =readpublisher.nextLine();
          publisherList[0].pubAddress =readpublisher.nextLine();
          publisherList[1].pubID =readpublisher.nextLine();
          publisherList[1].publisher =readpublisher.nextLine();
          publisherList[1].pubAddress =readpublisher.nextLine();
          publisherList[2].pubID =readpublisher.nextLine();
          publisherList[2].publisher =readpublisher.nextLine();
          publisherList[2].pubAddress =readpublisher.nextLine();
          publisherList[3].pubID =readpublisher.nextLine();
          publisherList[3].publisher =readpublisher.nextLine();
          publisherList[3].pubAddress =readpublisher.nextLine();
        }

    }
    readpublisher.close();
}

public static void printPublisher(publisherDetails[] publisherList)  
{
for (int j=0 ;j<publisherList.length; j++)
     {
       output("Publisher ID : " + publisherList[j].pubID);
       output("Publisher : " + publisherList[j].publisher);
       output("Publisher Address :  " + publisherList[j].pubAddress);
     }

}  


public static void addPublisher() throws IOException
{
   FileWriter inputPublisher = new FileWriter(new File("publisherMain.txt",true);
   newPublisher(inputPublisher);
}


public static void newPublisher(FileWriter inputPublisher) throws IOException
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    output("Please enter publisher ID");
    String ID = scan.nextLine();
    inputPublisher.write("\n"+ID);

    output("Please enter Publisher ");
    String publisher = scan.nextLine();
    inputPublisher.write("\n"+publisher);

    output("Please enter publisher Address");
    String pubAddress = scan.nextLine();
    inputPublisher.write("\n"+pubAddress);

    scan.close();
    inputPublisher.close();
  }
```

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code. It's *really* hard to read at the moment, with indentation all over the place. I strongly suspect you don't really need ~100 lines of code to demonstrate the problem, either - please reduce this to a [mcve].

Comment: (I'd strongly recommend that you start following Java naming conventions more closely too - `publisherList` isn't a conventional class name.)

Comment: @JonSkeet noted, thanks! i'm pretty new at this so please forgive me, i'll be sure to keep this in mind the next time round! :D

Comment: You don't need to wait for the next time. You can (and should) edit your *current* question.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason why you can't just use an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)? It seems pretty wasteful to read the whole file once, just to determine the size of the array, and then read it again to get the actual values of the records.

Comment: Hmm, there is no reason, but I'm pretty new to Java & I wasn't aware of it. This is a project for a software class i'm taking currently and my knowledge in java is pretty limited, but it'd be helpful if you could elaborate on how I could use an ArrayList? Thanks! :D

Comment: See Oguz' answer for an example. An `ArrayList` in Java is basically a dynamic array. You can add new elements to it and it will resize automatically, so you don't need to know the number of elements when creating it. The respective methods for that can be found in the API. It can be iterated by using an enhanced for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to search with a key through the data, then I think you should use a map. You must change "createPublisher" and "printPublisher" methods.

```
public static Map<String, publisherDetails> createPublisher(File publisherMain, Scanner readpublisher)
        throws IOException {

    Map<String, publisherDetails> publisherMap = new HashMap<String, publisherDetails>();
    publisherDetails newPublisher = new publisherDetails();
    while (readpublisher.hasNextLine()) {

        newPublisher.pubID = readpublisher.nextLine();
        newPublisher.publisher = readpublisher.nextLine();
        newPublisher.pubAddress = readpublisher.nextLine();
        // Fill the map 
        publisherMap.put(newPublisher.pubID, newPublisher);
        readpublisher.nextLine();
    }
    readpublisher.close();
    return publisherMap;
}

public static void printPublisher(Map<String, publisherDetails> publisherMap) {
    // loop through the whole data
    // or you can search with key like publisherMap.get(pubId); 
    for(Map.Entry<String,publisherDetails> entry : publisherMap.entrySet()){

        output("Publisher ID : "       + entry.getValue().pubID);
        output("Publisher : "          + entry.getValue().publisher);
        output("Publisher Address :  " + entry.getValue().pubAddress);
    }

}
```

Or you can use ArrayList of course. Here is how.

```
public static List<publisherDetails> createPublisher(File publisherMain, Scanner readpublisher)
        throws IOException {

    List<publisherDetails> publisherList = new ArrayList<publisherDetails>();
    publisherDetails newPublisher = new publisherDetails();
    while (readpublisher.hasNextLine()) {
        readpublisher.nextLine();
        newPublisher.pubID = readpublisher.nextLine();
        newPublisher.publisher = readpublisher.nextLine();
        newPublisher.pubAddress = readpublisher.nextLine();
        // Fill the list
        publisherList.add(newPublisher);

    }
    readpublisher.close();
    return publisherList;
}

public static void printPublisher(List<publisherDetails> publisherList) {
    // loop through the whole data
    for(publisherDetails publisher : publisherList){

        output("Publisher ID : "       + publisher.pubID);
        output("Publisher : "          + publisher.publisher);
        output("Publisher Address :  " + publisher.pubAddress);
    }

}
```

Comment: Generally, but especially when using collections, you should always use the interface and not the implementation type in return values and parameters. So `printPublisher()` should take a `List` parameter and `createPublisher()` should return a `List`.

Comment: I've tried the code and it works perfect but when I try to write new information into the file, it only displays the new information and not the previous information.

Comment: Do you mean adding new attributes to publisherDetails class ? Firstly, you should add the new attributes in the publisherDetails class and then make sure that readpublisher has the new features. And also, you may check output method.

Comment: I mean it reads through the text file and there are 4 different PubID, (other details) but it prints all three fields 4 times with the same data from txt file (the last data)

Comment: Oww, I see. You should add readpublisher.nextLine(); in the while loop. :)

Comment: Thanks, I did. But, I received this output
 
Publisher ID : 04-7733903
Publisher : Wiley and Sons
Publisher Address :  45, Lincoln Blvd, Chicago
Publisher ID : 04-7733903
Publisher : Wiley and Sons
Publisher Address :  45, Lincoln Blvd, Chicago

this is my input in the txtfile

03-4472822
Random House
123, 4th Street, New York
04-7733903
Wiley and Sons
45, Lincoln Blvd, Chicago